# GTA V Online Pacific Standard Glitch

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

Have they patched the Pacific Standard Heist Glitch (where the leader dashboards right before the heist is over) or can I still do it?

Answer (score 1):

No, I was looking through patch notes and a forum posts leading up to the past week (Following the valentines update) and there has been no mention of a patch for the Pacific Standard Host Glitch.

Comment: No problem, just be more careful when talking about exploits :)